# How to pass a method to Thread constructor?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I pass a Method2 to thread as shown in below if i write code as shown in below it shows an error Error

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)' has
>   some invalid arguments

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread : ");           
            Thread obj = new Thread(Method2);
            obj.Start();                   
            Console.ReadLine();
        }       
        private static int Method2(int a)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
```

When i use the following code it works

```
Thread obj = new Thread(() => Method2(1));
```

But why it's not working when i pass delegate object

```
delegate int del(int i);

del d = Method2;

Thread obj = new Thread(d);
```

What is the difference between above 2 , in 1st case i used Lambda expression in second case directly passed delegate object is there any thing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread` constuctor takes two types of delegates, `ThreadStart` and `ParameterizedThreadStart`. To see what type of method these delegates accept you can create it and the constructor will show you, so for example,

```
var parameterMethod = new ParameterizedThreadStart(...
```

If you type the above you will see the delegate takes a function with one object as the parameter and returns void.

```
void (object) target
```

This is why your Method that takes an int will not work because the signature does not match the delegate target signature. **When you wrap it in a lambada, you are actually passing in a method that takes no parameters and returns void, so the Method2 signature is not even looked at**. Wrapping method calls with a lambada like this can be very useful for getting the signature to match.

```
delegate void del(object obj);
del d = () => Method2(1);
Thread obj = new Thread(d);
```

There is an infinite number of possible method signatures so Threads and Tasks keep it simple and say if you want to pass something, pass a single object. Since all types derive from object, this lets you pass in anything you want, then cast it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Thread obj = new Thread(() => Method2(some_int_value));
```

Comment: ThanQ It works fine but can't we pass delegate object instead as shown in below 
        ` delegate int del(int var);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            del d = Method2;
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread : ");
            Thread obj = new Thread(d);`